# Pandas: Merge small DataFrame into large, overwrite with small

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to do something that I think should be a one-liner, but am struggling to get it right.

I have a large dataframe, we'll call it `lg`, and a small dataframe, we'll call it `sm`.  Each dataframe has a `start` and an `end` column, and multiple other columns *all of which are identical between the two dataframes* (for simplicity, we'll call all of those columns `type`).  Sometimes, `sm` will have the same `start` *and* `end` as `lg`, and if that is the case, I want `sm`'s `type` to overwrite `lg`'s `type`.

Here's the setup:

```
lg = pd.DataFrame({'start':[1,2,3,4], 'end':[5,6,7,8], 'type':['a','b','c','d']})
sm = pd.DataFrame({'start':[9,2,3], 'end':[10,6,11], 'type':['e','f','g']})
```

...note that the only matching `['start','end']` combo is `['2','6']`

My desired output:

```
   start  end type
0      1    5    a
1      2    6    f    # where sm['type'] overwrites lg['type'] because of matching ['start','end']
2      3    7    c
3      3   11    g    # where there is no overwrite because 'end' does not match
4      4    8    d
5      9   10    e    # where this row is added from sm
```

I've tried multiple versions of `.merge()`, `merge_ordered()`, etc. but to no avail.  I've actually gotten it to work with `merge_ordered()` and `drop_duplicates()` only to realize that it was simply dropping the duplicate that was earlier in the alphabet, not because it was from `sm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set `start` and `end` columns as index and then use `combine_first`:

```
sm.set_index(['start', 'end']).combine_first(lg.set_index(['start', 'end'])).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Knew I was missing something simple.  Thank you!